# Azure Function App process time can it be extended by extending the QueueMessage's invisibility until it is processed?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-queues, azure-function-app, queuetrigger

I am working with Azure Function Apps in Python, that has two Functions HTTPTrigger & QueueTrigger, in the QueueTrigger I  call my custom code, which takes more than 10 mins to process. I changed it from 5 mins to 10 mins in host.json `{"functionTimeout": "00:10:00"}` . My question is, is there a way to extend process time by updating the QueueMessage content 
 or visibilityTimeout or Timeout? In other words, would the Function App process time be extended if you extend the message's invisibility until it is processed? see Python API [QueueService.update_message()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-queue/azure.storage.queue.queueservice.queueservice?view=azure-python#update-message-queue-name--message-id--pop-receipt--visibility-timeout--content-none--timeout-none-) 
Is there any other serverless options to run long processes?

> Updates the visibility timeout of a message. You can also use this
>   operation to update the contents of a message.
>
> This operation can be used to continually extend the invisibility of a
>   queue message. This functionality can be useful if you want a worker
>   role to "lease" a queue message. For example, if a worker role calls
>   get_messages and recognizes that it needs more time to process a
>   message, it can continually extend the message's invisibility until it
>   is processed. If the worker role were to fail during processing,
>   eventually the message would become visible again and another worker
>   role could process it.
>
> `update_message(queue_name, message_id, pop_receipt, visibility_timeout, content=None, timeout=None)`

Comment: if you need Functions that can run longer then 10min, you need to switch to App Service Plan. There you can run Functions indefinitely: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#timeout

Comment: That's probably what I need. I was under the impression consumption plan was the only way to do serverless. Thanks!

Comment: I just made that an answer and added a note regarding serverless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need Functions that can run longer then 10 min, you need to switch to App Service Plan. There you can run Functions indefinitely: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#timeout

Be aware, though, this isn't fully "serverless" any more in terms of scaling. App Service plan won't scale more or less indefinitely in the same way as consumption plan scales. Plus you pay the fixed price for the app service plan.